# what is the best way of securing Rest Api using spring boot java applicqation?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I want to secure my Rest API , Which is the best way of securing the Rest Api ? I want to use username and password to authenticate in the request header. I am confused with OAuth2 and JWT token. If possible provide me samples to understand.Advance thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this [link](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way). It explains some differences between username:password vs OAuth.

**Basic API Authentication w/ TLS**

Basic API authentication is the easiest of the three to implement, because the majority of the time, it can be implemented without additional libraries. Everything needed to implement basic authentication is usually included in your standard framework or language library. The problem with basic authentication is that it is, well “basic”, and it offers the lowest security options of the common protocols.  There are no advanced options for using this protocol, so you are just sending a username and password that is Base64 encoded.  Basic authentication should never be used without TLS (formerly known as SSL) encryption because the username and password combination can be easily decoded otherwise.

**OAuth1.0a**

OAuth 1.0a is the most secure of the three common protocols.  OAuth1 is a widely-used, tested, secure, signature-based protocol.  The protocol uses a cryptographic signature, (usually HMAC-SHA1) value that combines the token secret, nonce, and other request based information.  The great advantage of OAuth 1 is you never directly pass the token secret across the wire, which completely eliminates the possibility of anyone seeing a password in transit. This is the only of the three protocols that can be safely used without SSL (although you should still use SSL if the data transferred is sensitive). However, this level of security comes with a price: generating and validating signatures can be a complex process.  You have to use specific hashing algorithms with a strict set of steps.  However, this complexity isn’t often an issue anymore as every major programming language has a library to handle this for you.

**OAuth2**

OAuth2 sounds like an evolution of OAuth1, but in reality it is a completely different take on authentication that attempts to reduce complexity. OAuth2’s current specification removes signatures, so you no longer need to use cryptographic algorithms to create, generate, and validate signatures.  All the encryption is now handled by TLS, which is required.  There are not as many OAuth2 libraries as there are OAuth1a libraries, so leveraging this protocol for REST API security may be more challenging.

Last year, the lead author and editor of the OAuth2 standard resigned, with this informative post.. Because of this instability in the spec committee and because OAuth2’s default settings are less secure than OAuth1 (no digital signature means you can’t verify if contents have been tampered with before or after transit), we recommend OAuth1 over OAuth2 for sensitive data applications.  OAuth2 could make sense for less sensitive environments, like some social networks.

**Custom Protocols**

Custom API authentication protocols should be avoided unless you really, really know what you are doing and fully understand all the intricacies of cryptographic digital signatures.  Most organizations don’t have this expertise, so we recommend OAuth1.0a as a solid alternative.

Even if you are willing to take this potentially perilous road, there is another reason to avoid it: because it is custom, no one other than you will be able to use it easily.  Only use custom authentication protocols if you are willing to support client libraries you can give to your REST API callers (Java, Ruby, PHP, Python, etc) so your users can use these protocols with little or no effort.  Otherwise the API will be ignored.

What did we choose? At Stormpath, we do use a custom authentication protocol.  It is very similar to OAuth1, but with many enhancements (for example, unlike OAuth1, Stormpath’s scheme uses the request body when computing the signature to ensure the body cannot be tampered with, among other things like additional key derivation functions).  But again, this algorithm is useful only to clients that are using our SDKs that implement this algorithm.  We also support other common protocols for clients that can’t use our SDKs.

**Why Use API Keys vs. Username/Password Authentication**

One other technique we use is generated API Keys instead of traditional username/password authentication.  That decision is well-documented on our blog, but it’s also very important for API security, so here’s the Cliff Notes on API Keys:

Entropy

API keys/secrets are usually a long series of random characters that are difficult to guess.   Username/password are typically much smaller in length, use common words, are generally insecure, and can be subject to brute force and dictionary attacks.

Password Reset Problems

Passwords are reset often.  If you use the password as part of your API authentication scheme, API access would fail every time the password is changed.

Speed

Best practices say to encrypt your passwords in the database to limit a potential data breach.  This increases overhead for each request when authenticating a user.  Unique API keys authentication skips the hashing step and therefore speeds up your calls.

So, decide what is most appropriate for your implementation!

Comment: You should summarize the content of the blog-post into your answer. If the link ever becomes unavailable, your answer might lose its validity. Link only answers are therefore a kind of bad smell here on SO